# Guardar entidad en matriz bidimensional

Tags: java, android, android-layout, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy realizando una app en Android que debe mostrar cierta información sobre el inventario de diferentes tiendas, para acceder a la bd uso un web service (uso un stored procedure pero yo no tengo permisos para manipular dicha información) y ya en el main tengo una Entidad Productos que almacena tienda, codigo_producto, nombre_producto, talla y cantidad y necesito mostrar esos datos en forma de matriz, las tallas deben quedar como encabezados de la tabla, algo así:

Tienda    | Codigo_Producto | Nombre_Producto | 15 | 15.5 | 20 | 20.5 |.....

5      |    191783       | PIRMA CALZADO   |  0 |   2  |  0 |  1   |....

No sé si alguien pudiera orientarme sobre cómo ir guardando los datos de la Entidad en un arreglo bidimensional o un Arraylist en JAVA.

En el ciclo for recorro lo que encuentra, luego guardo los datos en variables y éstas las paso a un objeto llamado Talla y ese objeto lo guardo en un ArrayList (listaTallas), pero me está costando mucho acomodar las tallas como cabeceras y que las cantidades coincidan.

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                SoapObject bank = (SoapObject) t.getProperty(i);

                String tienda = bank.getProperty("Tienda").toString();
                String p_talla = bank.getProperty("Producto_talla").toString();
                String nombre_producto = bank.getProperty("Nombre_Producto").toString();
                String talla = bank.getProperty("Talla").toString();
                String cantidad = bank.getProperty("Cantidad").toString();

                Talla oTalla = new Talla(tienda, p_talla, nombre_producto, talla, cantidad);
                listaTallas.add(oTalla);

            }
```

Una vez que los datos del objeto se pasan a la lista, los uso para ir creando la tabla con un tablelayout, pero no sé cómo hacer que las cantidades me coincidan con las tallas y que las tallas no me salgan repetidas, ya que un producto puede tener varias tallas. No sé si hay alguna función que sirva como se hace en los datagridviews de Visual o algo parecido.

[image: Hasta el momento esto es lo que me muestra (también quiero quitar los repetidos de tallas y productos):]

Comment: Puedes elaborar un poco más sobre el código que ya tienes y porque buscas de guardar estos datos en matriz en vez que en un Objeto de clase `Producto` que podrías desarrollar y luego guardar en un `List` o un `Map`?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy elaborando una app en android, en efecto guardo los datos en un objeto y luego los paso a un Arraylist, pero estoy teniendo problemas para que me queden las tallas como columnas y que las cantidades coincidan con las tallas.

Comment: Entonces el problema esta en la vista,  y la plataforma es Android?

Comment: Así es, me he vuelto loca buscando formas de lograrlo, incluso modificando las consultas, pero mi problema sigue en poner las tallas como cabeceras, y se me ocurrió que tal vez se pueda hacer con una matriz y ya después sólo pintar la vista.

Comment: Podrías revisar `TableLayout`. Recuerda de dar los más informaciones que posible cuando preguntas.